# android 5.1 do not ask for security warning for camera access

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-security

I had developed app that is working fine with other version of android except android 5.1 "LG thing".

I created my own camera activity in app and while running app on other versions of android, It ask for Security warning pop up on screen.

If Pressed allow app shows camera....

In android 5.1 the security pop up never shown
Please refer this image

What I want this pop up on android 5.1
[image]

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: asking permission comes in android 6 it will not ask you in android 5

Comment: This screenshot is from android 5.0

Comment: Hey dude, security warning varies from phone to phone based on the user's anti-virus or security app installed.You can't do anything (if you have a goal to bypass it or something .. you don't seem to be a legit programmer.)

Comment: So why it poped up on android 5.0, It make my app crash if camera is not allowed.

Comment: What am I missing in permission?

Comment: @AkshayPatil did you find any solution to this ?